# Vue - How to use a different socket.io port in tests?

Tags: vue.js, server-side-rendering

I'm using socket.io in a webpack/vue project (built by vue-cli).

This is how the client initialized socket.io:

```
var socketlib = require('socket.io-client')
var socket = socketlib('http://localhost:3000/')
```

I would like to use a different port in testing, in order to enable me to run tests while the dev server is up (3001 for tests).

How do I make the client access 3001 port in tests? Do I need server-side rendering for that?

Comment: you need some way to tell your vue-app that it is in dev mode. This could be done by using server side rendering, for example: setting a config variable. Or two different apps, but they would also be put into the HTML on server side. Basically: yes you need server side rendering any way.

Comment: @keksnicoh that's what I thought. Convert into an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The answer is yes**.

Any approach is basically server side rendering.  One must to provide information to the application that it is in dev mode. Either you have a separate dev-app.js, some javascript configuration, some element attribute or what so ever. Even if one has a separate dev-app.js, it must be rendered into the HTML that the application script is dev-app.js then.